# Why isn't my image height scaling correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, image-resizing

So I'm working on a gallery where images are shown in a 200x200px list item

```
#gallery-list-ui li {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In order to have portrait / landscape images use the entire height/width, I'm using javascript to decide if I should set either height or width to 100%.

```
var portrait    = ($img.height() > $img.width() ? true : false);

if(portrait){
    $img.css({'width' :'100%', 'height' : 'auto'});
} else {
    $img.css({'height' :'100%', 'width' : 'auto'});
}
```

The result is that portrait images scales correctly

```
<img src="img.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
```

but landscape images scales 100% of its original height and is not limited to the height of the list box.

```
<img src="img.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: auto;">
```

[image]

What am I missing here? Can anyone explain why this is happening?
See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/smyhbckx/5/

Comment: It appears your immediate `img` element's parent container doesn't have a defined `height` and therefore won't stop the `img` from display full `height`, but `width` works, even if not set, as a `div` defaults to 100%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add height to .img-container:

```
.img-container{
    height: 100%;
}
```

CSS height is very strict. It is based on the element's direct parent's height. The direct parent of the img is `.img-container` - which doesn't have a height (meaning `height: auto;`). The parser recognize this as an unknown number, and thus your img height is not scaled.

Comment: Well since a web page was designed to flow primary verticaly (as you can notice your mouse only have a vertical scroll). The height of most elements are designed to "flow" as much as possible, while the width are mostly limited. You can see that feature most clearly in `display: block;` elements, which default to 100% parent's width while allow for flexible height.

Comment: The only difference is the behavior of `width: auto;` vs `height: auto;`. When the image try to compare with its parent width and find that its parent has `width: auto;`, it can automatically recognize the meaning of that as "100% of next tier parent width". While it is not the same for height, `height: auto;` means an undefined number. In fact, your `.img-container`'s height itself can flow much larger than 200px despite having a 200px height parent, because `height: auto;` in HTML mean "as much as you want".

Comment: @Steven Simply put, elements inherit percent size from its parent and the height is by default set to grow with its content, but the width isn't, hence the difference in their behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `object-fit:cover;height:100%` property on image and also add following styling to container

```
.img-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue

https://jsfiddle.net/smyhbckx/7/

Comment: Huh... adding height and width to `img-container` worked. But why is it working for width and not height in the first place?